# luakit browser installation fail

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Luakit browser on Raspberry Pi on Rasbian 7 (Wheezy). However when I execute

```
sudo apt-get install luakit
```

I get following output from console:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install luakit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 consolekit : Recommends: libpam-ck-connector but it is not going to be installed
      Breaks: udev (< 204-1) but 175-7.2 is to be installed
luakit : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.5.1) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: liblua5.1-0 but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: libunique-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: lua5.1-filesystem
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
epiphany-browser-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-icon-theme-symbolic lesstif2 libavahi-gobject0 libclass-isa-perl libgeoclue0 libgssglue1
libnss3 libswitch-perl libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libxp6 ttf-dejavu-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
udev
The following packages will be upgraded:
udev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 668 not upgraded.
60 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/850 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,022 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Unquoted string "p" may clash with future reserved word at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 5, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
debconf: Problem setting up the database defined by stanza 5 of /etc/debconf.conf.
Unrecognized character \xF2; marked by <-- HERE after j[#h`nGe_u<-- HERE near column 35 at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 5, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 17) line 2, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 17) line 2, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
(Reading database ... 84442 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_215-17+deb8u2_armhf.deb ...
Unquoted string "p" may clash with future reserved word at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 5, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
debconf: Problem setting up the database defined by stanza 5 of /etc/debconf.conf.
Unrecognized character \xF2; marked by <-- HERE after j[#h`nGe_u<-- HERE near column 35 at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 5, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 16) line 2, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 16) line 2, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 5.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_215-17+deb8u2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/udev_215-17+deb8u2_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I wonder if it is possible to fix this issue without upgrading current distribution Wheezy to Jessie ?